# Need a curve that peaks in the middle of my screen...

Tags: geometry

X goes from $801$ to $-50$.
Y should peak at $240$, start and end at $400$.

I've been toying around with my Texas, how could I express a curve like the one I try to describe above? I want to create a sunrise, seen far far away like on the edge of a curve?

here is a image of what i think the curve should look like: [link](http://bildr.no/view/1057186)

xstart: 801, xstop: -10
ymax: 240
ystart + end = 400 (ish)

Comment: Could you please draw a rouch sketch of what you want and post an image?

Comment: i have supplied a linke to a image :D

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be a parabola through the three points $(-50,400), (375.5,240), (801,400)$, which would be $y=\frac{160}{375.5^2}(x-375.5)^2+240$

Comment: Alternatively, finding the circle through those three points gives approximately $(x-375.5)^2+(y-885.782)^2=417034$, or $y=-\sqrt{417034-(x-375.5)^2}+885.782$.

Comment: mmmm... works. the curve is maybe a litt sharp (look at my image), but ill guess it does the job. creating a small game for my phone, just a test thingy

Comment: @JonasMeyer:  You might try Jonas Meyer's circle.  Your image looks more like that.

Comment: @Jason94: I believe Ross meant that last message for you, not me.

Comment: @JonasMeyer:  I believe OP gets a ping for any comment, even without the @.  I wanted you to see the comment as well.

Comment: "I believe OP gets a ping for any comment, even without the @." - that's for the comments under OP's question, not in comments under an answer.